# How do factorization machines work for degree 3?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, polynomial

I understand that factorization machines as polynomial regressions, but their second degree coefficient form a matrix that is factorized as two smaller matrices.

Some approaches for higher-order factorization machines involve sums of element-wise products (see eq. 3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.07195.pdf), but is there a consensus over a method?

For example, [this library](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/polylearn/index.html) implements degree 3 FM.

P.S.: maybe there is a need for a FM tag?